# Plotting 83 variables of 1 observation in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame with 131 observations, each with 83 variables (villages with various crime counts - violent, car theft, etc, in various years). I need to select one observation (one village) and plot specific variable (e.g. violent crime count) against different years.

I have subsetted the village by:

```
my_data<-  data[which(data$WardName =='village_name'), ]
```

Now I have 1 observation with 83 variables.

How do I plot for example 'Vehicle Crime Count' for years '2007-2008', '2008-2009', '2009-2010'? Variable names would be "Vehicle.Crime.Count.2008.2009",               "Vehicle.Crime.Count.2009.2010", etc.

I tried to create a new data frame

```
year <- c('2007-2008', '2008-2009', '2009-2010', '2010-2011',
          '2011-2012', '2012-2013', '2013-2014', '2014-2015')

crime <- c('Total Crime Count', 'ASB', 'Burglary Dwelling', 'Criminal Damage', 
           'Deliberate Fires', 'Domestic Abuse', 'Theft of Pedal Cycles', 
           'Vehicle Crime', 'Violence Against the Person', 'Violent Crime')
```

But that would mean I'd need to copy all the figures from the original data frame for each crime/year and I don't think that's the way to do it. I already have all this info in the original data set.

What should be my next step?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'd approach the problem by first reshaping the data to long format, i.e. with columns for `village`, `crime`, `year`, and `count`. You can then very easily subset the data however you want with respect to those variables.

This type of reshaping operation is pretty straightforward with packages `reshape2` or `tidyr`.

Here's an example.

First we create some fake data that (I think) match the format of your data:

```
d <- data.frame(Village=LETTERS[1:5],
                Vehicle.Crime.Count.2008.2009=rpois(5, 20), 
                Vehicle.Crime.Count.2009.2010=rpois(5, 20),
                Vehicle.Crime.Count.2010.2011=rpois(5, 20),
                Vehicle.Crime.Count.2011.2012=rpois(5, 20),
                Violent.Crime.Count.2008.2009=rpois(5, 20),
                Violent.Crime.Count.2009.2010=rpois(5, 20),
                Violent.Crime.Count.2010.2011=rpois(5, 20),
                Violent.Crime.Count.2011.2012=rpois(5, 20))
```

Load some useful packages:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

Reshape the data to long format:

```
d_long <- gather(d, key=Crime, value=Count, -Village) %>%
  separate(Crime, c('Crime', 'Year'), '\\.Count\\.') %>%
  mutate(Crime=factor(gsub('\\.', ' ', Crime)), 
         Year=factor(sub('\\.', '-', Year)))
```

To explain the above:

- the `%>%` "forward pipe" operator chains expressions together, so, for example, `1:10 %>% head` will send the result of `1:10` to the `head` function, as the first argument. See `` ?dplyr::`%>%` `` for more details/examples.
- `gather` stacks all the columns (except `Village`, which we've excluded with `-Village`) into two columns: one referred to as the `key`, which contains the old column name that was associated with an observation, and one referred to as the `value`, which contains the old cells' value. We specify that we want the final key column to be called `Crime` and the final value column to be called `Count`.
- `separate` takes the text in the `Crime` column and splits it into two columns, specified as `Crime` and `Year`, splitting at `.Count.` (i.e. sticking everything before `.Count.` into the `Crime` column, and everything after `.Count.` into the `Year` column. The separator itself (`.Count.`) is discarded.
- `mutate` creates new columns, or overwrites existing ones, with given values. Here we tidy up the `Crime` and `Year` columns by replacing periods (`.`) with spaces in `Crime` and with hyphens in `Year`.

The result is:

```
head(d_long)
##   Village         Crime      Year Count
## 1       A Vehicle Crime 2008-2009    16
## 2       B Vehicle Crime 2008-2009    12
## 3       C Vehicle Crime 2008-2009    15
## 4       D Vehicle Crime 2008-2009    20
## 5       E Vehicle Crime 2008-2009    23
## 6       A Vehicle Crime 2009-2010    28
```

We can now filter these data to the subset of interest, and plot them:

```
filter(d_long, 
       Crime=='Vehicle Crime', Year %in% c('2008-2009', '2009-2010', '2010-2011')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, Count, group=Village, color=Village)) +
    geom_line() +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to have a go. Should I reshape the whole data set (including all the villages that I'm not interested in) or just the one village I want?